# can't find more options in project page in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am playing with someone's project on GoogleCode. When I add `include<string>` and compile it, I got

```
1>  Toolbar.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xlocale(323): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xlocale(323): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
```

From 
[/EH (Exception Handling Model)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx),
I know I have to Exception Handling Model. But in this project's property page, there are only four fields under 'Configuration Properties':

```
General
Debugging
VC++ Directories
NMake
```

Unlike in a new Win32 project created by Visual Studio, I can't find `C\C++`. Should I set Exception Handling Model in `makefile` file? And what exactly I have to do if I want to set this mode to `Yes(/EHSC)`. Thanks in advance.

---

Here is the makefile.msvc file in this project's root folder. Since it is long and I found it is difficult to format its text content to code sample here, I upload it to a upload provider. Here is the link. If there is an better option than doing so, please let me know.
[My MakeFile.msvc](http://www.scribd.com/doc/94104567/Make-File)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since you have a `make` (`nmake`) project, you are supposed to set everything yourself in the `makefile`.

Post the makefile or a relevant snippet and we can point out the place where to add the flag. Usually it will be either a line that references `cl.exe` or a variable named `CFLAGS` or similar. It depends which convention the creator of the `makefile` chose.

Comment: Thank you, I uploaded the makefile.

Comment: Thank you again, I successfully set it!